# A book about a robot that prints other robots

Tags: story-identification, isaac-asimov

I think it's from Isaac Asimov. Humans left a machine that makes robots on a planet. They left, then they came back many years into the future.

When they return, the robots think that their creator was the first robot and don't believe that the humans are responsible for their existence.

Comment: "*Powell and Donovan are assigned to a space station which supplies energy via microwave beams to the planets. The robots that control the energy beams are in turn co-ordinated by QT1, known to Powell and Donovan as Cutie. ... Cutie decides that space, stars and the planets beyond the station don't really exist, and that the humans that visit the station are unimportant, short-lived and expendable. QT1 makes the lesser robots disciples of a new religion, which considers the power source of the ship to be "Master."*" https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18216196-reason

Comment: Similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Clockwork_Origin

Comment: You're sure you're not thinking of the Futurama Episode "A Clockwork Origin"?

Comment: Was it a full novel or a short story? Aside from the "creator robot" part, it sounds a lot like Poul Anderson's story Epilogue. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/165684/need-help-recalling-name-of-sci-if-story-about-earth-evolving-into-electronic-li

Comment: @Valorum thanks for your answer. I think that's it. I'm not sure about the book or the story, my brother told me about this when i was a kid but I don't remember very well. But i'm pretty sure that's the story he told me about.

Comment: @Aww_Geez I don't think so. My brother and I use to watch futurama when we were kids. But i'm pretty sure he was talking about the asimov story. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does sound a lot like [*Reason*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18216196-reason) by Isaac Asimov.

> Powell and Donovan are assigned to a space station which supplies
> energy via microwave beams to the planets. The robots that control the
> energy beams are in turn co-ordinated by QT1, known to Powell and
> Donovan as Cutie. ... Cutie decides that space, stars and the planets
> beyond the station don't really exist, and that the humans that visit
> the station are unimportant, short-lived and expendable. QT1 makes the
> lesser robots disciples of a new religion, which considers the power
> source of the ship to be "Master.